# How to extract numbers(Integer) from String field in database and find the maximum

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, jpa, max

I have an entity. One field named "number" consists of String. It is a number + some text information. For example:
131-MOD
11853-ARO
983-AKK
etc.

My task is: get the maximum of the first number. So, I have to extract Integer value from String "number" and find the maximum from it. For the examples higher, it would be the numbers 131, 11853 and 983. So, the maximum is 11853. I have to get this Integer value as a result.
Here i have my try using Hibernate. But it working with only Integer values. How to extract number, i have no idea.

```
public Integer getMaxNumber()
{
   return (Integer) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("select max(id) from EmployeeTripCard s").uniqueResult();
}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following JPQL query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(id, 1, LOCATE(id, '-') - 1) AS INTEGER))
FROM EmployeeTripCard s;
```

We can use `LOCATE` to find the index of the first `-`, then call `SUBSTRING` to find the initial number.  Note carefully that we also need to cast this resulting string to an integer, in order for `MAX` to behave the way we want (numbers as text don't always sort the same way as actual pure numbers).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. But, how can i modify this to valid extract this numbers 123,djfkd or 374_aks. i. e. excract number for the first "non numeric symbol" like ,.-_+-, letters etc? There is some keyword?

Comment: If you don't know the separator character, then I don't think you can write an exact HQL query.

Comment: return em.createQuery("SELECT MAX(cast( SUBSTRING(s.id, 1, LOCATE(s.id, '-') - 1) AS integer)) FROM EmployeeTripCard s").getSingleResult();

Comment: i tried this, but it tells me that "index can't be negative". i dont understand, where? i have only one record in database and it is "123-aos" on id field. My Locate position should be 4. What's wrong

Comment: @Vytsalo Then your assumption is probably incorrect, and most likely you have data in your table which does not have a `-` in it.